# WPF : ListBox.ItemTemplate doesn't react when click on text or image wpf xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I'm new to Xaml and WPF . I'm using the following code to extract botton title and image from RSS feeds .
The problem that the botton react only when user click on the border ... it dosen't react when user click on text or image .

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
      <DataTemplate >
                    <Button  Background="{Binding C:AccentColors}" Width="400" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <Grid Width="400" Height="100" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Image Source="{Binding XPath=enclosure/@url}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  />
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"react"*? Also, your Button has no event, or command.

Comment: I manage the click behavior with binding the Selected element to à stack panel  like this 

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LB1}" Width="auto" > ....

Comment: Remove the Button: I think you'll have the desired feature

Answer (score 0):

The button **is** taking the clicks.  You need a handler, either a command binding or if you're not using MVVM - a code behind method:

```
<Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
```

Handler will look like this:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I manage the click behavior with isSelected property of the listbox like this 

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LB1}" Width="auto" > ....

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Click event in your button.

```
<Button  Background="{Binding C:AccentColors}" Width="400" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="MethodNameHere".....
```

and also you have to create and implement the method in the Window C# file

Comment: I manage the click behavior with isSelected property of the listbox like this 

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=LB1}" Width="auto" > ....

Answer (score 0):

The common mistake is that somebody placed TextBlock on top of button without realizig it, because TextBlock has transparent Background.

Visually, the Text of TextBlock  may be outside Button, but since TextBlock alignment is set to strech by default, it fills entire area.

hard to say if this is your case...

```
<Grid>
   <Button Content="I'm not working" Margin="0,100,0,0" />
   <TextBlock Text="I'm in top left corner" />
<Grid />
```

if you set TextBlock.Background to Red, you entire grid would be red.

Comment: The structure of my Xaml is 
[code]
<Grid>
   <Button >
   <TextBlock  />

</Button >
<Grid />
[/code]

Comment: From what you have posted, we cannot help you more. Thee is something wrong elsewhere in your vode. I can only recommend you to use tools like xamlspy to investigate your visualtree at runtime